# Row Count Transformation in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using the 'Row Count'component to count the rows in the data flow. I have decalred a new variable called In_rec. But it is not populating the correct rowcount. Please let me know the Input Column properties for the same.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it's not populating the correct row count? Are you trying to read the variable outside of the data flow task and can't? Is your scope set properly (i.e.-not just the data flow task if you're trying to access it in another task)?

Answer (score 1):

hi did you try assigning the variable to the Variablename property of the Row count transformation. That is how you get the value of the row count persisted inside the package at runtime.